# themeforce (happytables framework) implementation

Tags: theme-development, functions, framework

OK, I've been trying to implement themeforce in the roots theme and couldn't make it work. Then I tried it with the twentyeleven theme and still couldn't make it work. Instead all I get is an HTTP Error 500.

PLEASE someone that has already implemented this, could you copy-paste the appropriate lines from your functions.php file?

WP 3.4, latest themeforce from https://github.com/themeforce/framework
What am I missing?
I git cloned it inside my theme, added the wpthumb (also from git) 'cause it doesn't get copied when you clone the framework theme and then tried editing my functions.php

Answer (score 1):

Founder here. Most people use the framework to see how we've solved certain challenges, so they'll re-use individual code blocks. It's not plug and play as is noted at the very top of the github readme:

> Warning: At this point & without our full infrastructure, you will be
>   missing certain functions (primarily in the food area). We hope to
>   consolidate these at one poin in the future. For now however, this
>   repository should be used as a reference as a opposed to a solution
>   you depend on. We also do not provide downloadable themes.

Cheers

Noel

Comment: thank you. I know.. I finally did manage to get it right.